# iphone Memory gets freed in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: iphone

I have been testing my iPhone debug build on both my device and simulator with activity monitor, leaks, and object allocations. The code is pretty well optimized so I have decided to test the release build. I went into the project Menu and set the target build to be release, I then added the necessary header paths that my app is using to the headers search paths and ran the release build on the device with the above mentioned instruments. What I have noticed now is that memory that was freed when I used the debug build does not get freed when using release version. There is one place in my App that I remove a scroll view with some images which frees up a significant amount of memory when I use the debug build, but no memory is freed up in that place when I use the release version. Does someone have any ideas where I need to start looking at? did I setup my release build wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some objects will be cached in an application memory (e.g., `UIImage`) and will be freed automatically when the device is running out of memory.

As long as your application does not crash when memory goes critical, I think there's nothing to worry.